How long does David live a life as an edgerunner?
In the anime TV show, Cyberpunk Edgerunner, David receives a military-grade implant and joins a group of underground criminals, living a life as an Edgerunner.
Do we know how long does he enjoy being an Edgerunner?
The timeline in this amine show is a bit vague, there are little evidence that we can use as time stamps:

David receives the military-grade implant and joins a group of Edgerunners
Not long after, they botch an operation which results in the death of several members
Unknown amount of time passes
David receives more implants, especially a pair of Gorrila arms and continues to live a life as a criminal, taking orders Faraday as the team leader
Unknown amount of time passes
David eventually has a spectacular shodown with Adam Smasher

